# Reload Page after Delete Action in MongoDB, Express, Node, Handlebars App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So Im trying to do delete an instance of my model in a web app that has MongoDB database and Express.js routing. What I would like to delete the instance when a user clicks the delete button. I wish to accomplish this with AJAX. Right now, the delete action is working in Mongo.

I need to make the page reload to rerender the page and reflect the new changes to the database.

Here is my Route :

```
router.delete("/articles/:id", function(req,res){
  Article.remove({"_id": req.params.id})
   .exec (function(err, doc){
     if (err){
         res.send(err)
     } 
     else{
        res.send(doc);
     }
     }).then(function(res){
        res.redirect("saved")
     })
 })
```

Here is the button:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn deleteButton">Delete Article</a>
```

Here is the AJAX code for the delete:

```
$(".deleteButton").on('click', function(){
console.log(this.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id'));
var delete_id = this.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
$.ajax({
    method: "DELETE",
    URL: "/articles/" + delete_id
}).done(function(res){
    console.log(res);
}).catch(function(err){     
    console.log(err);
  })
})
```

Just for reference here is the saved.handlebars file I am using to render the html:

```
<div class="row">
 {{#each contents}}
  <div class="col s12 m3 l4" data-id ={{this.id}} id="articlePanel">
  {{!-- <h2 class="header">Saved Article</h2> --}}
   <div class="card horizontal red lighten-3 hoverable">
    <div class="card-stacked">
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>{{this.title}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action" data-id = {{this.id}}>
          <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red pulse"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">See Notes</a>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn deleteButton">Delete Article</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Currently, I can see that the Delete is working. But I have to manually reload the page for the newly deleted section to disappear. I have tried `res.send(doc)` instead of `res.render`. I have also tried `res.redirect`. Still with no success.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: `URL` should be `url`

Comment: I tried that.Didnt work

Comment: When i do that, the ajax request doesnt happen at all. No error message, nothing.

Comment: And have you tried `console.log(delete_id)`

Comment: yeah. Im getting the id for sure. But I just restarted the server and now I am getting a 500 error

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes when you define `data-id` attribute:

```
<div class="card-action" data-id="{{this.id}}">
```

Replace `catch` method with `fail`, there is no method called catch in the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) object:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "DELETE",
    URL: "/articles/" + delete_id
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {     
    console.log(errorThrown);
});
```

Also, the `remove` method is not returning the removed document unless if it was called from the model instance, Or if you use `findBuIdAndRemove` method:

```
Article.findByIdAndRemove( req.params.id, function (err, doc) {

    if (err) return res.json({ success: false });

    res.json({ success: true });

});
```

One last thing, You can not send redirect response to ajax call, let the browser reload the page for you:

```
.done(function(res) {
    if (res.success) {
         // reload page
         window.location.reload();
    }
})
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, consider [marking it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)